# delete-c-electric-paren deletes active region in CC mode with delete-selection-mode enabled

Tags: region, cc-mode, balanced-parentheses, electric-pair-mode

I've the `delete-selection-mode` enabled. In programming modes like Python and Lua, or in general modes like Fundamental or Text, when there's an active region, pressing `(` rightly wraps the region with the parenthesis pair like `(` *region* `)`. I understand that this behaviour is not special and the key `(` is just bound to `self-insert-command`.

However, when I'm in CC mode the region is deleted and I see this `(|)`, which is not the desired behaviour as there was an active region; this seems appropriate when there's no active region. Upon investigation I understand that disabling `delete-selection-mode` fixes the situation.

In CC mode, giving `M-(` does the job, however, I don't want to special case in my brain saying, for CC mode do `M-(` and for every other mode do `(`. I want a simple solution where I can just do `(` and instead of deleting the selection, the active region should get wrapped.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Please try with `emacs -Q` and report whether behavior still exists.

Comment: @nispio Wow, thanks! Updated the question. I realize that having `delete-selection-mode` seems to be the issue. However, on other programming modes the issue isn't present even when it's enabled. `cc-mode` is the faulty one; when `delete-selection-mode` is enabled, it just deletes the selection instead of wrapping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer by legends2k](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17364/93) is correct.  However, if you want to fix the issue without having to modify your local emacs installation, you can also work around the issue by adding the following lines to your personal .emacs:

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  (progn
    (require 'cc-mode)
    (put 'c-electric-paren 'delete-selection nil)
    (put 'c-electric-brace 'delete-selection nil)))
```

Comment: Is it ok to move the `require` inside `progn`? Would it gain us anything?

Comment: @legends2k  I made that change.  It doesn't hurt, but I'm not sure that we gain anything in terms of deferred loading either, if that's what you are asking.  I'm really not sure that the `eval-after-load` even gains us anything, but I have never understood the ins-and-outs of autoloading very well.

Comment: Same here, even I don't understand the mechanism very well, but I think by the time `require` is run, the `cc-mode` is already ON so it wouldn't load anything not already present (which, I guess, would be the case with `require` had it been outside `eval-after-load`).

Comment: `(require 'cc-mode)` inside `(eval-after-load "cc-mode"...)` is always a nop. Actually, you could probably just run the `put`s eagerly even without `require`ing or `eval-after-load`ing.

Comment: @npostavs  The only thing I know for sure is that `require` is necessary.  Also, I disagree that the `require` inside of `eval-after-load` is a nop, since I get different behavior (it doesn't work) when I comment that line out.

Comment: Ah, you're entirely correct. It's only when doing `(eval-after-load 'cc-mode...)` that the `require` is not needed. Also `(eval-after-load "cc-cmds"...)` works without a `require`. Although it seems wrong that `(eval-after-load "cc-mode"...)` works differently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in CC mode](http://sourceforge.net/p/cc-mode/mailman/message/34384301/) which is already fixed in the master branch. Since you have an older stable build, you can replace your copies of the files

- [`emacs-24.5/lisp/delsel.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/delsel.el)
- [`emacs-24.5/lisp/progmodes/cc-cmds.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/cc-cmds.el)

from git and compile them within Emacs with `M-x byte-compile-file` or on terminal using

```
emacs -Q -batch -f batch-byte-compile delsel.el progmodes/cc-cmds.el
```

The respective `.elc` files will be updated. Reload the `.elc` files (`M-x load file`) or restart Emacs. The issue would be fixed now.